# window.close() doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ipad, chrome-ios

I open a new window with window.open() to redirect users to the oauth login page. However, after successful login when the user is redirected back to my app the previous window with the window.open call does not close itself in ios.

On the iPad it would close the wrong window and on the iPhone it wouldn't close the window at all. The code works fine on Android and on desktop versions of Chrome and Firefox.

After much rooting about, I found a fix (posted below). If anyone has any better ideas or root causes, please post here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some searching, I found this tweet which posts a workaround - https://twitter.com/#!/gryzzly/statuses/177061204114685952 by @gryzzly

Copied here in full

> window.close() doesn't work on iOS after window.open()ing or
>   target="_blank"? do setTimeout(window.close, timeout); where timeout >
>   300.

This along with removing a `.focus()` in which I focus on the parent window before closing the new window completely solved the problem for me.

Comment: tweet poster here! better suggestion is to actually use `window.addEventListener("load", window.close);`

Comment: I've moved on from that project so I'm not sure whether I had actually tried 'load' or not, but that makes sense. Will file it away for the future, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

here is what I ended up getting to work...
never could get the window.close function to work; even in the setTimeout as shown above

I tested this on:
    windows XP : Chrome20,Firefox12,IE8
    Android gingerbread : android browser 
    Android Ice Cream  : android browser, Firefox 
    Ipad           : default browser (i assume its safari) 
    Iphone 3gs and 4s  : default

---

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=\"JavaScript\">
    function refresh() {
        var sURL = unescape("http://(some web page)/");
        window.location.replace(sURL);
    }
    function closeWindow() {
        var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
        var isiPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
        if (isiPad || isiPhone) {
           setTimeout( \"refresh()\", 300 );
        } else {
           window.close();
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

*......  and the html code .......*

```
<p><input class="bigbutton" type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="closeWindow()"></p>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

ios 12、13 OK

```
<p>If the page stops. Please press the button below to continue.</p>
<input id="button" name="button" type="submit" value="Close">

<script>
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  if (ua.indexOf('iPhone ') > 0) {  
    document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.close();
    }, false);

    document.querySelector('#button').click();
  } else {
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```