# Window.close working sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: javascript

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.close?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.close),
window.close() won't work in FF if window is not opened with window.open();

We have implemented ExtJS in a project and a new window/tab is opened with anchor tag and target='_blank'. In new window, there is close button with js code: 'window.close();'.

As per mozilla standard, this code should not work at all but strangely it works in some cases and doesn't work in some cases.

Can anyone provide some hint/suggestion or workaround please?

Comment: You want a workaround for something that does work sometimes, but shouldn't work at all? Just remove the code and the link. Problem solved.

Comment: I think you misread something. `window.close()` will only work on windows opened with `window.open()`. You're trying to close the window, which called `window.open()`. Which in turn, wasn't opened this way, and thus cannot be closed.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Can you suggest any workaround for this issue?Surprisingly, it's working sometimes so it has became more crucial to deny for the solution.

Comment: @Yoshi: ok, I got you, have removed the code from my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

Was having some issues on Chrome for iOS (in other browsers it works just fine). For that call close after a timeout > 300 as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712923)

So code should look like:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
setTimeout(window.close, 1000);
```