# button does not close window in Safari. Works for all other browsers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an Entity Framework app that is working fine in IE, Edge, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox.

But this particular part is NOT working in Safari on a Mac Mini, Macbook, or iPad.

I have a web page to display my player statistics and I open it like this with the press of a button:

```
function ShowPlayerStats(playerId) {
  window.open("xServer/game/playerView.html?playerID=" + playerId, "Your Player Stats", "width=400,height=900");    
}
```

That little window that pops up, playerView.html has a button called Close.  It is supposed to close the Window when the player is done looking.

It looks like this:

```
function closeStats() {
  console.log('closing stats window');
  self.close();
}
```

And is fired with this button:

```
<input type="button" id="statsClose" value="CLOSE" onclick="closeStats()" />
```

Now it works in all browsers except Safari for some reason.

In the Safari developer console, I do see thie message: "closing stats window" but the window is never closed.

How can I get this to work in Safari too?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a known issue - Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712923/998096

Comment: @OfirBaruch thanks but that is from 8 years ago, I can't imagine something being broken for that long.

Comment: And if you use "window.close()" instead of "self.close()"?

Comment: @OfirBaruch unfortunately `window.close()` does not work either.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, although the link is older but the last answer in it provide a solution. You may try to call window.close()  directly onclick, excluding logging into console.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **self.close()** to close opened browser from ios mobile app using **window.open()** function it will not work, you can use **history.go(-(window.history.length - 1))** to close the open window. :)